# rsync files-from and directory structure

Tags: rsync

I have been copying some files and folders by building an rsync command manually using a string list in the shell.

For remote file structure like:

```
/home/foo/
  media/
    bigfile.bin
  somedir/
    a.txt
    b.json
```

I would write:

```
rsync -Pavz my_remote:/home/foo/{media/bigfile.bin,somedir} .
```

The resulting local file structure is

```
./bigfile.bin
./somedir/
  a.txt
  b.json
```

**The directory structure is important.** `bigfile.bin` is not locally in a `media/` dir but `somedir` was copied recursively. This is what I want.

Now, I have a script to build a list of files to be transferred so I can use

```
rsync -Pavz --files-from=list.txt my_remote:/home/foo
```

where `list.txt` is

```
media/bigfile.bin
somedir/
```

Now, the resulting local file structure is

```
./media/
  bigfile.bin
./somedir/
  a.txt
  b.json
```

I now have the `media` directory that I don't want, I guess because of the common base directory as `my_remote:/home/foo`. Is there any way to recover the previous behavior while using `--files-from`? If I turn on `--no-R`, that flattens everything, but actually I still want `somedir/`. More generally, the desired behavior is "take the base part of the specified path (`bigfile.bin`, `somedir`) and copy it & its contents contents recursively, ignoring parent directories (`media`) in destination paths."

I could also use a script to build the rsync command with curly braces to be expanded by the shell as I was doing initially, but I potentially have to deal with a headache of character escapes in remote filenames that I'd rather avoid by using `--files-from`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following (`rsync` versions => 2.6.7).

In your `list.txt` add a dot slash `./` at the end of the path you don't want to be included:

```
media/./bigfile.bin
somedir/
```

In this case `./` makes `rsync` ignore the path `media/` of the line `media/./bigfile.bin`.

From the man page

```
--relative, -R
        ...

        It  is  also  possible  to limit the amount of path information that is
        sent as implied directories for each path you specify.  With  a  modern
        rsync  on the sending side (beginning with 2.6.7), you can insert a dot
        and a slash into the source path, like this:

            rsync -avR /foo/./bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
```

I've just tested and it seems to work as I understand you intend.